# Update a variable in the service from multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in search of a better way to do the following:

I have this **service**:

```
dashboardApp.service('MessagesService', function () {
   var message = "";

    this.update = function (new_message) {
        message = new_message;
    };

    this.get = function () {
        return message;
    }
});
```

and let's say I have this **controller**:

```
dashboardApp.controller('GroupPageController', function($scope, MessagesController){
    $scope.message = MessagesController.get();
})
```

that $scope.message variable is in my HTML page:

```
<h3 ng-bind="message"></h3>
```

and let's say I have this second **controller**:

```
dashboardApp.controller('ChangeController', function($scope, MessagesController, $http){

    $scope.sendEmail = function () {

        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/enterprises/vouchers/_send",
            data: {
                group_id: group_id,
                group_student_ids: group_student_ids
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            MessagesService.update(response.message);
        }).error(function () {
            console.log("failed")
        });

    }

})
```

so here, when some button is clicked, this function gets data from a web API and updates the variable inside the service. Then, I expect the $scope.message variable inside the first controller to update too so that HTML page will change too. But that does not happen. So, I use $watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return MessagesService.get();
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.message = MessagesService.get();
    }
});
```

Then, everything works as I want it to. But I read some articles where it is said that $watch should not be used inside the controllers.

How can I achieve this functionality without $watch?

Comment: Its fine to use $watch inside your controller.

Comment: @alsco77, really? it is good news) [Here](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html) is the link I mentioned, which says "DON'T use $watch in controllers"

Comment: as far as i can see he seems to only be watching scope variables and not values changing from external services

Comment: ya.. sure. you can use $watch inside your controller. If not you need play with JavaScript. It will just make you code complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between controller without a watcher. You just need to declare the service on the scope, then you can update properties of the service with your scope.

Here is a sample:    http://plnkr.co/edit/zNGnkfEsCIvLssCyHivg?p=preview

```js
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    
    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedDataService', function($scope, sharedDataService){
    
      $scope.sharedDataService = sharedDataService;
      
    }]); 
    
    app.controller('mySecondCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedDataService', function($scope, sharedDataService){
    
      $scope.sharedDataService = sharedDataService;
      
    }]); 
    
    app.service('sharedDataService', [function(){
      return {
        someData: "Share Me"
      }
    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
  
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
      Controller one:
      
      <input ng-model="sharedDataService.someData">
      
    </div>  
    
    <br>
    
    <div ng-controller="mySecondCtrl"> 
      Controller two:
      <input ng-model="sharedDataService.someData">
      
    </div>  
    
  </body>

</html>
```